# Expand collapse button for multiple sets

Tags: html, css

Trying to use expand and collapse button.
Currently, on click of `ExpanseCollapase1` button expands `ExpanseCollapase2` as well.

Want to show only `data` and `data1`, on click of `ExpanseCollapase1` button. And show `data2` and `data3`, on click of `ExpanseCollapase2` button.

Working fiddle of the same: http://jsfiddle.net/wj9Lf35u/17/

Would like to avoid using jquery code.
Thank you.

First set:

```
<div><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidd   en="false"></i></a>ExapndCollapse1
<p class="collapse multi-collapse">
    data 
</p>
<p class="collapse multi-collapse" >
     data 1
</p>
```

Second Set:

```
<div><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidde   n="true"></i></a>ExpandCollapse2
    <p class="collapse multi-collapse">
        data 2
    </p>
    <p class="collapse multi-collapse" >
        data 3
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change data-target to custom classes instead of `collapse multi-collapse`. Here I used `lev1` and `lev2` for the different data groups. `lev1` for `data` and `data1` and `lev2` for `data2` and `data3`.

```css
a[data-toggle="collapse"], a[data-toggle="collapse"]:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a[data-toggle="collapse"] span{
  padding: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<!--jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" />

<!--code--->
<div><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".lev1"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidd en="false"></i><span>ExapndCollapse1</span></a>
  <p class="collapse multi-collapse lev1">
    data
  </p>
  <p class="collapse multi-collapse lev1">
    data 1
  </p>
</div>
<ul><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".lev2"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidde n="true"></i><span>ExpandCollapse2</span></a>
  <p class="collapse multi-collapse lev2">
    data 2
  </p>
  <p class="collapse multi-collapse lev2">
    data 3
  </p>
</ul>
```